# Pass an input string to different jsp page base on button clicked using nested form

Tags: java, jsp

I'm trying to pass a `trackingNo` to jsp page based on which button is pressed.
I created 2 buttons, `addnew` and `search`.
The `addnew` is supposed to get the input `trackingNo` from the input field and pass it to tracking.jsp if it is pressed,
and the search is supposed to get the input `trackingNo` from the input field and pass it to a home_student_result.jsp.

I'm not sure what is the correct way to do it, so I tried using a nested form with "add" id in one form and "srch" id in another.
After running it, only the top form works. The inner form doesn't work.
Can anyone please help me, or suggest a better way to do it please?

```
 <div>
    <form id="add" method="post" action="tracking.jsp">
        <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
        <form id="srch" method="post" action="home_student_result.jsp">
            <input name="target" type="input" placeholder = "Search..." class = "text_search"/>
        </form>
    </form>
</div>
<button class="button_search" onclick="document.getElementById('add').submit()">
        Add New
</button>
<button class="button_search" onclick = "document.getElementById('srch').submit();">
    Search
</button>
```

Comment: You either need two separate forms, or to use JavaScript to set the action of the one form to the correct action, and then call form.submit which is exactly what @Swati's solution does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use only one `form` and click of button you can change the `action` value to particular value depending on button click and then submit your `form`.

**Demo Code** :

```js
function submit(value) {
  console.log(value)
  //if value is add
  if (value == "add") {
    //change action of form
    document.getElementById('forms').action = 'tracking.jsp'
    document.getElementById('forms').submit(); //submit
  } else {
    document.getElementById('forms').action = 'home_student_result.jsp'
    document.getElementById('forms').submit();
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
<!--add id to form-->
  <form id="forms" method="post" action="tracking.jsp">
    <i class="fas fa-search"></i>

    <input name="target" type="input" placeholder="Search..." class="text_search" />

  </form>
</div>
<!--add function with parameter(value of button) -->
<button class="button_search" value="add" onclick="submit(this.value)">
                Add New
        </button>
<button class="button_search" value="srch" onclick="submit(this.value)">
            Search
        </button>
```

Comment: OMG thank you so much @Swati.
I'm still new to java and jsp so i didnt know that i can insert script in the middle and call functions like you show.
thank you so much for the help, appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep both the forms independently and set the value of 'target' field using javascript. something like below .I've added id attributes to your code to work with vanilla javascript.

```
    <div>
    <form id="add" method="post" action="tracking.jsp">
        <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
        <input id="addText" type="input" placeholder = "add text"/>
        <button class="button_search" onclick="addToSearch()">
        Add New
        </button>
    </form>
    <form id="srch" method="post" action="home_student_result.jsp">
        <input name="target" id="searchValue" type="input" placeholder = "Search..." class = "text_search"/>
        <button class="button_search" onclick = "document.getElementById('srch').submit();">
        Search
        </button>
    </form>
</div>
            
<script>
    function addToSearch(){
     var textValue = document.getElementById('addText').value;
     document.getElementById('searchValue').value = textValue;
    }
</script>
```